# Simultaneity in spacetime diagrams

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames

In the following question it asks to deduce the order of events X,Y, and Z in the reference frame of Earth and the answer says that events Y and Z are simultaneous but I cannot intuitively grasp why this would be. Could someone explain this to me (sorry for the formatting).

[image]

[image]

Comment: they dont seem to be simultaneous

Comment: Exactly, but the answer makes use of light cones from both Y and Z which intersect the ct-axis at 2, is this correct reasoning to suggest they are simultaneous?

Comment: there seems to be misconception about simultaneity and simultaneous observing. They are not simultaneous events in Earths frame, but an observer at x=0 would see them both at the same time t=2, since at that time the light from both events would reach him. Note this is independent on reference frame, since every observer (no matter his movement) that is at time t=2 in the spot x=0 of Earths frame would see those lights at the same time.

Comment: I agree with Umaxo, theyare simultaneously viewed (cause of the finite speed of light), which is different. They are seen at the same time but do not occur at the same time as measured by clocks at Z and Y

Comment: To clarify the problem statement, this seems to be a source of the question: https://www.ibdocuments.com/IB%20QUESTIONBANKS/4.%20Fourth%20Edition/questionbank.ibo.org/en/teachers/00000/questionbanks/46-dp-physics/questions/123122.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, knowing the specific wording of the question and answer would help, but: the events are definitely not simultaneous in the usual sense of the word, because their time coordinates are definitely different. The order is $X$, then $Y$, then $Z$. However, the light (and hence all information) coming from $Y$ and $Z$ arrives at the observer at the same time, because light travels at 45° on a spacetime diagram.

This means that the observer "sees" (as in, actually see with your eyes, or with an instrument) $Y$ and $Z$ simultaneously, but they don't happen simultaneously in the Earth's frame, and that's what we usually care about in relativity.

Answer (score 0):

The observer initially at the origin will see the flash from Z and the flash from Y at t=2, so they will appear simultaneously at x=0. However, X and Y themselves are not simultaneous events in the reference frame as they occur at different values of t. I suspect we would need to see the exact wording of Question 6 before we could say whether the question was at fault.

Answer (score 0):

A locus of points approach might help. The line $ct'$ represents not just the time axis of the rocket frame, but the world line as well. $x'$ is the x axis for the rocket's frame.

It can be shown that lines of simultaneity in the primed frame are parallel to the rocket's x axis while lines of simultaneity for the earth frame are parallel to the earth's x axis. find equations for the line $t'=$constant, for example. So where does the line of simultaneity for Y and Z intersect the earth's time axis?

So while none of the three points are simultaneous in the earth frame, y and z are in the rocket's frame.

An important related question, Suppose an event is located on the time axis of the earth frame 2 seconds from the origin. What points on the rocket's time axis are the same distance from the origin in terms of the time space interval? Its important to realize this is not generally on a circle centered at the origin and passing through that point, but rather a hyperbola.